# How to fix rerendering component while reloading page on the same route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which is a child component. It has its own Route. When i try to reload the page on this route this component update itself two times instead of one. How to fix it? It is fetching the resource and is getting info two times insted of one.

I've tried to add some logic to parent component so it will pass through props what i need but it is already being passed through withRouter.

```
const ItemDetails = (props) => {
  const countryService = new CountryService();
  const [country, setCountry] = useState('');
  const [code, setCode] = useState(props.match.params.code);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCode(props.match.params.code)
    updateCountry()
  }, [])

  const updateCountry = () => {
    countryService
      .getByName(code.toLowerCase())
      .then((country) => {
        setCountry(country)
      })
  }

  return (
    <ItemView country={country}/>
  )
}
```

I expect the component to get info just once

Comment: Can you add the working code on codesandbox?

Comment: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Alopwer/countries-of-the-world-app) The component is in the folder item-details

Answer (score 0):

I've added a state [loaded, setLoaded] to my App component so that after it got info it sets loaded to true. When Item-details renders firstly loaded has default value which is false and it doesn't updateCountry()

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.isLoaded) {
      updateCountry(props.match.params.code);
    }
  }, []);
```